# Call different instances of same lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a lambda B function which accepts url from dynamodb and fetch the content of url. There is one lambda  A which read dynamodb table and send url as sqs message and trigger my B lambda. How can instantiate B lambda with single url. I am using python 3.

Comment: start with posting your code

Comment: "How can instantiate B lambda with single url." If Lambda is configured to trigger off SQS messages then it should be doing that for you. What is the exact issue you are encountering?

Comment: Lambda A read a table in dynamodb who have urls, send this url one by one to another lambda B who scrap data by that url, I need only one url lambda B. First lambda gives a list of urls, my need is select one url and send to one instance of lambda B

Comment: Add code and then it might be worth taking a look

Answer (score 0):

To invoke a Lambda function from Python, use the `invoke()` command.

From [Lambda — Boto 3 Docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke):

```py
response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='string',
    InvocationType='Event'|'RequestResponse'|'DryRun',
    LogType='None'|'Tail',
    ClientContext='string',
    Payload=b'bytes'|file,
    Qualifier='string'
):
```